# React Router. I want to loop through various links adding components

Tags: reactjs

Please see the image below for the code.
I am trying to create an object within my state of various pages to load with the Router. Everything is fine apart from the render, as you can see on the image  is what im trying to load. But it's not allowing me to add a variable? if i use `${item.name}` it takes the variable name but all of it as a string eg "". How can i pass this as a variable so when i extend my state I can access different pages with other relative urls.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageTwo from '../Content/PageTwo/PageTwo';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Routes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    name: PageTwo,
                    url: '/test'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <Route
                        exact
                        name={item.name}
                        path={item.url}
                        render={(props) => (
                            <{item.name}/>
                        )}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Link for code image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQQN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As i can make out, you want to render component `<PageTwo />` for path `'/test'`. However you cant use components name as you tried with `<{item.name} />`.

Instead you could store a mapping of the path and component name in object and use that as follows:

```
const Components = {
test: PageTwo
};
const MyComponent = Components[item.url];
return <MyComponent />;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the arrow function I was under the impression the word "return" wasn't needed?
https://codesandbox.io/s/6y6p2kpy1r

Please could you show me what you mean (App.js)
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it shortly after posting. Check updated answer.

Comment: @Lee Did that help?